# Tomcat VirtualHost different port

Tags: java, tomcat8

How can I configure Tomcat Server with virtualhost multiple port? I want to do it like this

1. ysite.com
2. ysite.com:8080

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

-> edit conf/server.xml configuration file and add a new connector for the port you would like to add. For example if you have a connector like that:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Just add a new connector like that, but altering the port parameter. That's all, restart and you're done.

Comment: Why redirect port?

Comment: Thank you works perfect. Another  question I have multiple domain yc1.com and yc2.com I want them to  in virtual host and diffrent port how can i configure that way?